# HTML/CSS: Making them elements besides eachother

Tags: html, css, scrollable

I have this issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MRvkT/

I want both boxes to be besides eachother and not under eachother. I tried figure out what was wrong, I even tried to remove the  that didnt help, but just made .nextPage and .prevPage buttons(see css) disappear.

How can I make them besides eachother?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/jfhartsock/MRvkT/1/

You simply need to apply float:left; here

```
.showprofile-image-scrollable-container
{
    position: relative;
    width: 110px;
    float:left;
}
```